# JSoup get absolute url of an image with special characters

Tags: android, url, character, jsoup

i am working with JSoup and Android to get image urls from some site but some urls contains special characters like (é,è,à...) example :

http://www.mysite.com/détail du jour.jpg

the element.attr("abs:src") returns the same url as above

till now no problem to retrieve the url but when i submit this url in the code below it returns file not found (i grabbed this function from an example on the internet) :

```
public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
 try {
   URL url = new URL(address);
   Object content = url.getContent();
   return content;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

i think the problem is in the url format because when i get the real address of the image in google chrome :

http://www.mysite.com/d%C3%A9tail%20du%20jour.jpg

and submit it in the code like : 
    URL url = new URL("http://www.mysite.com/d%C3%A9tail%20du%20jour.jpg");

the image loads correctly so how to get this formatted url from JSoup?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `URLEncoder` for the extracted url from the JSoup.

Something like:

`URL url = new URL(URLEncoder.encode(address));`

The spaces between will be replaced with special character values %something

Comment: URLEncode.encode(myurl, "utf-8")  gives me "http://www.mysite.com/d%C3%A9tail+du+jour.jpg" which is not what i need the correct url looks like "http://www.mysite.com/d%C3%A9tail%20du%20jour.jpg"

Comment: Have you tried some other charset encoding like HTTP.ISO_8859_1 for the second parameter?

Comment: with HTTP.ISO_8859_1 still gives me D%E9tail+du+jour.jpg by the way the source code of the html page indicates that the charset=utf-8

Comment: i found a trick i think by replacing the "+" by %20 but i dont know if it is the correct approach the URLDecoder.decode translates the url to its previous state without replacing the %20 by "+" before decoding isnt that wierd?